# The role of "minimal" minimal primes 

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring of finite Krull dimension $n$. I'm interested in results where those minimal primes $P$ of $R$ play a role that sit at the end of a prime chain of maximal length, i.e. 
$$P=P_n \varsubsetneqq ... \varsubsetneqq P_0.$$

Examples are:

- $\dim(R/P) = \dim R$
- Additivity and reduction formula for multiplicity $$e(I;M) = \sum_Pe(I;R/P)\lambda(M_P)$$

BTW: Do these primes have a particular name ?

Comment: "Minimal primes of maximal dimension".  

Comment: Or just "primes of maximal dimension".

Comment: ..although a quick google search suggests that "minimal primes of maximal dimension" may be more common.

Comment: Avoid them in a local ring, inductively, using the Prime Avoidance Lemma, and you will have a system of parameters in your hand!